# Xcode 6.1.1 not compiling: Black Screen

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, osx-yosemite

I am on a mac book pro, Newly installed Yosemite.
It is about two years old, and I have just installed Xcode.
I opened a brand new project, and ran it, but all I got was a huge black screen, that takes, ages to load. And when it does it jumps into the normal menu section of an Iphone, and the app can't run!

I have just delved into iOS developing.

Comment: What type of project is it (iPhone app, Mac app, etc.)? And what do you mean by 'normal menu section of an iPhone'?

Comment: Do you think a computer can run all that code, and load up a test of it in no time? Well your answer is it can't, it's just like a normal simulator, when on the first run it takes a while to complie it, but after a few runs the black screen doesn't stay there as long. So the black screen is your computer compiling your app, because when you get to the 'normal selection menu of an iphone', the app opens up pretty quickly. And if the app can't run/open up you must have a bug in your code.

Comment: I shouldn't have a bugg in my code, since I didn't edit it at all.

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17618663/908929

Start the simulator and from the simulator main menu:

```
[IOS Simulator] -> [Reset Content and Settings]
```