# Ionic emulate ios - Error

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm getting this following error after I ran my app on my own ios device.

```
No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-6 simulator
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159):
Invalid device state
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159):
Invalid device state
ENOENT, no such file or directory '/Users/cauealmeida/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/5C6DA43E-3993-4260-87EE-73FEB27DE181/system.log'
Error code 1 for command: ios-sim with args: launch,/Users/cauealmeida/Documents/jobs/dev/ionic-maptest/map-test/platforms/ios/build/emulator/map-test.app,--devicetypeid,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6,--stderr,/Users/cauealmeida/Documents/jobs/dev/ionic-maptest/map-test/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--stdout,/Users/cauealmeida/Documents/jobs/dev/ionic-maptest/map-test/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--exit
Error: /Users/cauealmeida/Documents/jobs/dev/ionic-maptest/map-test/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
```

I've tried with `ionic emulate ios -cls` from different projects and the same error is shown.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

**Here are the steps you can use to correct this issue:**

1) Empty the 'platforms' folder in your Ionic project

2) Re-run **ionic platform add ios**, **ionic build ios**, and **ionic emulate ios** without sudo

3) Still getting a permissions error, make sure all the files in your user's home folder actually belong to that user by running

**sudo chown -R username /Users/username**

Answer (score 1):

We fixed this using the [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17618663/1747491), which was just to `Reset Content and Settings` in the `Simulator` menu.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download ios simulator.
Go to xcode and download ios 9 or other simulator.

you also need to install ios-sim using your terminal.

sudo npm install -g ios-sim

also check and confirmed your device is connected properly.
connected device you see in xcode window