# In Xcode 9.2, In simulator, iPhone's screen shows just blacked out screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode9.2

I have my ViewController our right side and iPhone 7 simulator running the same program on the right hand Side bottom.

And as you can see my Storyboard has also been greyed out. Everything in the storyboard is clickable but greyed out.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should try what is written here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17618663/8069241

Comment: hi @Parth can you edit your question, the whole question is based on a link that i seem. I just looked at the screenshot, did you assigned ViewController class to View on storyboard ?

Comment: yes, I have assigned that

Comment: Have you tried debugging the view hierarchy?

Comment: Not yet. But, now i again deleted this project and again pulled from the git and now it's working. I just don't know why.