# Xcode 9 simulator does not work after installing xcode 10 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I had Xcode 9.4.1 installed. I also installed Xcode 10 beta 6. 
Now the simulator no longer works correctly, it opens up but does not display anything. Precisely before it only displayed a black screen, then a colored screen ([here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdmAH.png)).

I have tried many solutions proposed here on StackOverflow but it did not solve the problem.

Below is what i did actually:

- run `defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferRendererHint 3`
- Restart mac
- Delete and reinstall `XCode 9.4.1`
- Delete `XCode 10 beta 6`
- Erase all content and settings on simulator
- Delete simulators on XCode and readd

Any help regarding the issue will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add links to SO related posts you have tried if you can.

Comment: [xcode-9-ios-simulator-becoming-black-screen-after-installing-xcode-10-beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50941865/xcode-9-ios-simulator-becoming-black-screen-after-installing-xcode-10-beta)

Comment: Now with new XCode 10 GM I've the same problem. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It happened for me once I have run Xcode 9.4 project on Xcode 10. It seems that the project has taken Xcode 10 preferences and once I get back to run the project on Xcode 9.4 conflicts happen between Xcode versions settings.

**SOLUTION:**

For me I closed both Xcode Versions, then restart my mac. Then everything is well and I'm able to run projects on simulators again for both versions of Xcode.