# Unable to shutdown device in current state: Shutdown Xcode Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have just install Xcode 10 beta, 
And when i run my code in iPhoneX (ios12 beta), the black simulator window comes.

[image]

I have tried

- Delete Derived data
- Restart simulator
- Restart my macbook
- Erase all content and settings

But nothing happens,
And same code  in my iPhone 8 simulator working fine,Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Download a simulator for an older version of iOS and try again

Comment: at Xcode 9.3 iPhoneX (ios11) simulator also showing same behaviour.
i have two version in macbook

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668445/launch-ios-simulator-from-xcode-and-getting-a-black-screen-followed-by-xcode-ha