# Black Screen on simulator when launching

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, ios-simulator

I'm currently facing an issue with my Xcode project.

Whenever I try to launch my project the screen goes black and stays there until I decide to close the simulator, I don't get no comments from Xcode on the debug area, BUT I remember seeing some error which stated that there were loads of classes such as: CSOSTransaction, CSRemoteControlClient, etc... implemented in both [path] and [path].

The pods I added into my project were:

[image]

This is what my simulator looks like after launching:

[image]

I've tried:

1. Resetting my simulator
2. Checked for duplicate frameworks
3. (Command + Shift + K) in Xcode
4. Uninstalling and Reinstalling Xcode
5. Cleaned DerivedData, CoreSimulator, iOSDeviceSupport
6. Resizing Simulator
7. Ran `defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator.IndigoFramebufferServices FramebufferRendererHint 0` on my Terminal to use OpenGL instead of Metal on my Simulator
8. Ran my app on my physical device
9. Uninstalling and Reinstalling all the pods I previously added to my project

Is there anyone who can help me on this one?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your simulator? Also, checkout this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14668445/launch-ios-simulator-from-xcode-and-getting-a-black-screen-followed-by-xcode-ha).

Comment: Also, could you post the code so we could duplicate?

Comment: can you please provide more info about the issue? a simple screenshoot

Comment: I've added more details with screenshots into my question.