# iOS 16 Simulator: Running an app in the simulator results in a ".xpc error"

Tags: xcode, macos, ios16, xcode14

After updating to macOS 13.0 Beta and installing Xcode 14.0 Beta we run an app where we set the target OS to 16. The following error occurs:

[image]

The iPhones simulators won't start either when started manually:

[image]

Here the detailed error message describing the issue:

```
Details

The operation couldn’t be completed. xpc error
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 64
Failure Reason: xpc error
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2022-06-17 16:19:12 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
}
--

Analytics Event: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone14,3";
    "device_osBuild" = "16.0 (20A5283p)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = "x86_64";
    "operation_duration_ms" = 44430;
    "operation_errorCode" = 64;
    "operation_errorDomain" = NSPOSIXErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_consoleMode" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_runnable_type" = 2;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator16.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "16.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 13.0 (Build 22A5266r)
Xcode 14.0 (21257.0.0.0.22) (Build 14A5228q)
Timestamp: 2022-06-17T11:19:12-05:00
```

Running the same app on a physical iPad running iPadOS 16.0 does not cause any problems.

Comment: Same issue here - Ventura 13.3, XCode 14.3 - cannot run any of the iOS 16.X simulators, the only ones that work are iOS 15.2.

Answer (score 21):

I met a similar issue, and I solved like below:
About this Mac > Storage > Manage > Developer and Open the screen, delete all cache, then it should work well.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Fixed the issue AND saved me some disk space!

Comment: worked for me on Ventura with xcode RC2...

Answer (score 3):

This error most likely represents the system app (SpringBoard in the case of iOS) crashing while Xcode is trying to launch your application.  There could certainly be other causes, but every report I've analyzed since Xcode 14 has been related to SpringBoard terminating (either crashing itself or being torn down because of a crash in antoher process, like SimMetalHost).

If you encounter this issue, please collect the following data (by running the commands in Terminal.app) while in this state (don't quit Simulator.app):

1. `sudo sysdiagnose`
2. `xcrun simctl diagnose`

File a feedback assistant report at http://bugreport.apple.com including the tarballs that resulted from those above two commands.  Feel free to add a comment here with your FB# if you want me to connect your FB report back to you or you have questions about your specific case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved for me by creating a new simulator in Xcode, with available OS version.

I think the OS version wasn’t available anymore (maybe deleted by error).

Hope it work for you too !

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:
1.Unistall Xcode
2.Reinstall Xcode

Comment: wow, so basically we need to lose 24 hours to fix this .. why Apple ... why ...

Comment: Instead of uninstalling whole Xcode, you can just uninstall particular iOS platform (Xcode -> Preferences -> Platforms) and install it again to reset emulator.That will  be much quicker than going through whole Xcode installation.

Answer (score -3):

This issue is solved, open finder > applications > xcode-beta > right click > get info > checklist 'open using Rosetta'